# Finding combinations in a list (Python)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a program in Python for solving PictoLogic games. I'm currently trying to write all possible boards from the horizontal numbers. So, I've got something like this:

```
lines = [[all possible combos for line 1], [same for line 2], [same for line 3], etc]
```

This lists are of different lenghts, and I also have another version in which they'll be a dict (with the indexex 1, 2, 3, etc.)

The idea would be to get all possible combinations of boards. For example:

```
lines = [["aa", "ab", "ba"], ["cc"]]
```

would lead into

```
[["aa", "cc"], ["ab", "cc"], ["ba", "cc"]]
```

That, but with lists of different lenghts and not knowing in advance the number of lines.
Thanks in advance, and sorry for bad english

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and pass the sub-list to this unction with an unpacking operation (`*`):

```
>>> lines = [['aa', 'ab', 'ba'], ['cc']]
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(*lines))
[('aa', 'cc'), ('ab', 'cc'), ('ba', 'cc')]
```

And if you want the result as list you can use `map` function :

```
>>> map(list,product(*lines))
[['aa', 'cc'], ['ab', 'cc'], ['ba', 'cc']]
```

Comment: Just note that the contents of the list are tuples, and not lists

Comment: @Zizouz212 Yeah and for convert them to list OP can use `map` function!

Answer (score 2):

Consider this way:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = ['x', 'y']

print [[i,j] for i in a for j in b]
>> [['a', 'x'], ['a', 'y'], ['b', 'x'], ['b', 'y'], ['c', 'x'], ['c', 'y']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do this with [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and the unpacking operator *:

```
lines = [["aa", "ab", "ba"], ["cc"]]
from itertools import product
print list(list(t) for t in product(*lines))
# >>> [['aa', 'cc'], ['ab', 'cc'], ['ba', 'cc']]
```